# is there a way to use zoom on a label

Tags: c#

I have a richtextbox and a label. The label auto updates to whatever line you're on in the richtextbox, but some people have requested a zoom function. When I zoom on the richtextbox the label becomes out of sync with the line. Is there a way to make the label the same zoom as the textbox or can I zoom the label at the same time?

This is my zoom code:

```
    private void toolStripButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float zoom = richTextBox1.ZoomFactor;
        if (zoom + 2f < 32f)
        richTextBox1.ZoomFactor = zoom + 2f;
    }

    private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        float zoom = richTextBox1.ZoomFactor;
        if (zoom - 1.25f > 0.25f)
            richTextBox1.ZoomFactor = zoom - 1.25f;
    }

    private void toolStripButton3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.ZoomFactor = 1f;
    }
```

Comment: http://forums.esri.com/Thread.asp?c=93&f=85&t=89815&g=1

Comment: @M.N.S. that doesnt really help and

Comment: Are you trying to Zoom the label, or trying to make it accurately reflect the current line? If the latter, what code are you using for line-determination now?

Comment: both would work i just need the text on the label the same as that in the richtextbox so that it wont go out of sync